# Removing form object hash while mapping through hash in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a hash with products.

```
products = Product.all
```

I want to map through the hash and remove an object from the hash if a certain conditions is met.

```
products.map do |product|
   product.delete if product.color == red
end
```

But this removes the object from the database. I only want to remove it from the products hash.

This is a simplified example where I could use SQL where statements. But in my real example this is more complex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array#reject`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/reject):

```
products.reject { |product| product.color == 'red' }
```

Or it's opposite [`Array#select`](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Array/select):

```
products.select { |product| product.color != 'red' }
```